# How to safely transfer some data from a server to an android device

Tags: android, encryption, public-key-encryption

I am working on an android application where I need to get some data securely from a server making sure that nobody has access to the data other than the application and the server.

For that I am planning to use public/private key encryption.
Is it the correct approach, or is there any better way?

I am new to both android and encryption. any pointers on where I can get some details/examples on how to implement this.

Thanks

Edit:
I am also planning to use private key for encryption and public key for decryption, which is  not the convention. Any issues with that?

Comment: Decrypting with the public key? Then it's pointless to encrypt the data in the first place.

Comment: So my server has some data which it sends to the client. but if the client has to decrypt it, it needs the private key, but I think it is a bad practice. so how should I do it?

Comment: Provided with those details, I'd recommend [TLS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security).

Answer (score 0):

pack your data in a JSON package, and encrypt it on the server with the same key as the client. Ensure that the key at the mobile side is hard coded (static field) of a class, and not in any xml files.
i have seen people doing this because "it's easier" but not a good practice. And then transfer it through https. (not http !)

If you want, feel free to read the [OWASP guide](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/OWASP_Guide_Project)